# Issue in getting access token from installed Facebook Android app

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-access-token, android-facebook

I am using Facebook SDK 3.0 for authentication. It works fine when facebook app is not installed on the device. If the facebook app is already installed on the device, I am unable to fetch the Access token value.

I am using the same code given in helloFacebookSampleActivity.java in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the [Single Sign-On](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/640/) feature provided by facebook. It allows user to sign in to your app if he/she is already logged-in, in the native facebook app, without having to re-enter the username and password.

To get this working you have to submit your Android key hash to your facebook profile. For more information on this please read the `Step 4` given [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/).